# Programmatically find out if system supports standby

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate, pinvoke, standby

This happens sometimes with Windows XP installations. Unless the display drivers are installed, power saving actions such as standby and hibernate are not supported.

Whether the system supports hibernate can be checked - http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/powrprof/IsPwrHibernateAllowed.html

Is there something similar for checking standby support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out all the porwer management functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373163(VS.85).aspx)

there is IsPwrSuspendAllowed which u could use it

Comment: I think the return value tells the user if sleep1,sleep2 & sleep3 which are hardware sleep states supported & not whether windows has enabled the Standby Mode.

Answer (score 3):

TO send a machine to sleep or hibernate use Win32 SetSuspendState Function Function

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373201%28VS.85%29.aspx

**BUT I could not find** anything that will tell if that mode is available without actually calling the above function & getting the error using GEtLastError() function.

EDIT: Use GetPwrCapabilities Function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372691%28VS.85%29.aspx

In that the structure SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES returns: 
SleepButtonPresent

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373215%28VS.85%29.aspx
which may help.